# Remember page contents

Tags: php, javascript, html

Some dynamic webpages somehow remember all its dynamic contents after leaving the page and when you push back button on browser the old page exactly looks like as you left it(including dynamic contents), some of them even remember which part of page you were focusing before leaving and after getting back scrolls exactly to part of the page that you were looking at.

I have a dynamic page that its contents change with ajax calls, I wanna make it possible that when user left and come back to page  see it exactly as  it was before leaving.

any helping idea is appreciated

Comment: What kind of dynamic contents? Kinda like https://www.google.com/ig ?

Comment: There is php, caches, cookies, all this stuff to remember your information. Your session may also have not ended

Answer (score 0):

I think some browser caches the page for a while if you navigator away from it. When you click back to go back to the page, it shows the page in it's previous state without calling the server. Not very reliable however.
You could bind a function to beforeunload event and save state settings to cookie. Like the parameters, form inpurts, and even scroll positions. Then when the user go back to the page, check the cookie for those settings and set the page to the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

Returning users can have stored data via a SESSION (assuming it hasn't expired) and a database.  Depending on how much data your planning on saving, you may only need the SESSION (I think there are performance issues, limitations on the amount you can/should store in SESSION?)

Here's a rough example of what I've done in the past. (via jQuery + REST + JSON + PHP). If you find data for that user, return it and populate accordingly.

```
<script>

function PopulateDOMElementsWithUD(user){ /* Do stuff on the DOM with User Data */ }

function CheckForUserData(){ 

   jQuery.getJSON('/user/getActiveData', function(user){ 

     //Data was found, use it
     if(typeof(user) == 'object' && typeof(user.id) != 'undefined' && parseInt(user.id) > 0){ 
        PopulateDOMElementsWithUD(user); 
     };

   }); 
} 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

  CheckForUserData(); 

}); 
</script>
```

Using a language such as PHP, you can check for a user's session data and then get the rest from the database:

```
<?php 
/* 
 * Assuming you already have some sort of handler for incoming XMLHTTPREQUESTs, 
 * and how that gets mapped to a method, moving along... 
 */
function getActiveData(){ 

    session_start(); 

    $user = array('id' => 0); 

    //assumes you only store the user's uid in the session
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){

        /*
         * Look up the user from the database based on uid stored in the session
         * This assumes that getUserDataById() also would return 
         * the default $user value (array('id' => 0)) if no user by that id is found 
         * in the database.         
         * I've also done something similar with try...catch and throw an exception 
         * if the user doesn't exist.
         */ 

        $user = getUserDataById(intval($_SESSION['uid']));

    }

    //There are plenty of frameworks out there that handle this stuff much more elegantly, but for sake of example, this would work. 
    print serialize($user); 
    die();

}
```

Hope that helps!